# Knockout.js complex table databinding

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I'm still quite new to knockout.js and have the following problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/ToastedSoul/wAyY7/

```
<td>
    <!-- what to put here? -->
</td>
...
"TableEntrySet":[
              {
                 "DisplayCode":"A",
                 "ColumnCode":"A4",
                 "RowCode":"L1",
              },
```

I get JSON data from the server and want to visualize the date using some tables. The tables labelled "level b text x.y" should contain the value of "DisplayCode" in the correct cell (first table: at "A4/L1" a "A" and at "A4/S1" a "A"). The data will never contain multiple entries for a single cell.

The "Summary table" should visualize all the previous tables layered on top of each other. So here, there might be cases when a single cell receives multiple values (in my fiddle: "A4/S1" will get "A" and "V", "A3/S4" will get "2V" or "VV")

I'm looking for an elegant way to populate those tables.

Since I will have to style some columns/rows/areas of the tables later on, I don't really need them to be created like I did in my fiddle (but if that's possible as well, why not!).

And if that's too easy for you knockout-pro's: 
What if I want to have just one table on the page buttons "previous" and "next" to browse through all those populated tables (including the summary one)?

Comment: Now with values and colors: http://jsfiddle.net/ToastedSoul/wAyY7/13/ . I wonder if it's possible to avoid repeated  `levelBItem.getTableEntry(Code, rowItem.Code)` calls

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're making the data for the innermost foreach the `RowNames` observable array. Each knockout foreach is contextual: it only has the data available to it that you pass in. The two exceptions are `$parent`, which gives you access to the immediate parent foreach's data, if it exists, and `$root`, which gives you access to the view model. Neither one really helps you that much here, since the data you need is in a list on the root view model. You *could* potentially use `$index` to try to pull out the right member of the other list, but that assumes that your `RowNames` array and it have indexes that match up, which may not be the case.

In general, your best bet here is to simply refactor so you're actually using the data you want to work with instead of `RowNames` and find another way to get the row header value.

Comment: I tried converting (during the mapping process) my 'TableEntrySets' into something more suited (some kind of associative array) that would allow for a straightforward bindings. But I'm still very new to knockout/javascript and I did not succeed with this. I've simplified the fiddle maybe a little too much; originally, I only looped over the rows, while I've hardcoded my four columns.

Comment: That's the idea. Maybe you can find a better way than hardcoding, but regardless, you need to loop over your rows.